# How to input the result of an instance into another instance

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and I tried doing this activity but I am so confused on the determineClass instance. When I run the code below, the 'classification' is not called.

Instructions:
The computeWeekly method is an instance method that should compute the weekly salary using the formula: fixedSalary * daysWorked * bonusRate. Whatever the computed weekly salary is, the determineClass method takes the value as an input and determines what classification the employee is (use your conditional structure research here).

The displayEmployee method just prints out all the attributes of each object. Name, Classification, Fixed Salary, WeeklyGross, and Bonus Rate. The appropriate classification should be reflected depending on the computed weekly gross.

```
public class Employee{
    public String name;
    public char classification;
    private double fixedSalary;
    private double weeklyGross;
    private double bonusRate;
     
    //constructor without a parameter
    public Employee(){
        this.name = "Paul";
        this.fixedSalary = 250;
        this.bonusRate = 5;
    }
 
    //compute weekly salary
    private double computeWeekly(double fixedSalary, int daysWorked, double bonusRate){
        weeklyGross = fixedSalary * daysWorked * bonusRate;
        return weeklyGross;
    }
     
    //take the weekly salary as input and determine what's the classification of the employee
    private char determineClass(double computeWeekly){
        if (computeWeekly >= 0){
            classification = 'A';
        }else if (computeWeekly >= 2000){
            classification = 'B';
        }else if (computeWeekly >= 2500){
            classification = 'C';
        }else if (computeWeekly >= 3000){
            classification = 'D';
        }else if (computeWeekly >= 3500){
            classification = 'E';
        }else{
            classification = 'F';
        }
        return classification;
    }
     
     
    //display information
    public void displayEmployee(){
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Classification: " + classification);
        System.out.println("Fixed Salary: " + fixedSalary);
        System.out.println("Weekly Gross: " + weeklyGross);
        System.out.println("Bonus Rate: " + bonusRate);
    }
     
    //main
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Employee employee1 = new Employee();
         
        employee1.computeWeekly(300, 7, 10);
        employee1.displayEmployee();
    }

}
```

Result:

```
Name: Paul
Classification: 
Fixed Salary: 250.0
Weekly Gross: 21000.0
Bonus Rate: 5.0
```

How can I set the value for the classification applying the conditional structure?

Comment: You never call `determineClass()`.

Comment: To clarify some terminology, `determineClass()` is a **method**, not an instance. `classification` is a field variable and it does not make sense to say "`classification` is never called" becase you cannot "call" variables. Instead you can say something like "`classification` is never set to a value".

Comment: With that said, to solve your problem, you need to call `determineClass()`. Also, since you `return classification;`, you should declare classification as a local variable. Additionally, you should learn about how to store a return value when you call a method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of classification with the following expression:

```
classification = determineClass(weeklyGross);
```

This has to be implemented between those two lines of code.

```
employee1.computeWeekly(300, 7, 10);
employee1.displayEmployee();
```

Comment: This won't quite work since `classification` is an instance field and `determineClass()` is an instance method. This means you cannot access them directly from `main()` because it is a static context.

Answer (score 0):

What is with

```
employee1.classification=employee1.determineClass(employee1.getWeeklyGross());
```

therefore you have to implement the function:

```
public double getWeeklyGross(){
return WeeklyGross;
}
```